# Is there a way to monitor Mac Notifications on El Capitan?

Tags: node.js, macos, applescript, apple-push-notifications, osx-elcapitan

Hey just a quick question for OSX developers - I'm basically trying to create a simple AppleScript file that monitors your notifications and triggers a Node.js script every time your Mac gets a notification. This shouldn't be too hard to do, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can send notifications with AppleScript, but you can't subscribe to them. For that you will have to resort to Objective-C or Swift. Triggering a NodeJS application is of course possible from within AppleScript, but that is not going to help you in this case.